# Workfront "Issue Collector"

Tags: attask, workfront-api

Currently working on a Workfront integration and trying to find a way to embed the "Create Task" form in our system, instead of creating our own form and calling the API.

Does Workfront has a feature similar to Jira's [issue collector](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-the-issue-collector-802592637.html?_ga=2.45562343.235431087.1513862417-2082735954.1503596079)?

An iFrame kinda does the job, but also makes the user able to navigate to other sections, which shouldn't be allowed in our scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a form to create an issue if you have the project setup as a request queue. The user still has to authenticate before being able to submit.